# Right arrow without italics

Tags: fonts, arrows, italic

How can I print a `\rightarrow` or `\Rightarrow` (I really don't care, I just want an arrow...) without the following words being in italics? This sentence added for grammar control.

Comment: You can simply define a new command to help you with the solution given by @MMA below. `\newcommand{\atob}[2]{$\text{#1}\rightarrow\text{#2}$}` uses two arguments. Then you just type `\atob{arg1}{arg2}`. If you use TeXstudio as editor, it recognize the new command and auto complete it for you when you start to type it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you are writing something like,
    `$Person\rightarrow Man$` and the text involved, are coming out in *italics*.

To begin with, it is incorrect to say that the text is coming out in italics. They are coming out in math mode.

Please try to see the difference between the following two,

```
\textit{Person}$\rightarrow$\textit{Man}

$Person\rightarrow Man$
```

[image]

From the first one, you get the output of your text in italics, from the second
one, text is actually coming out as math characters. See the different spacing among characters?

---

Anyway, one way of doing what you are asking for (arrows in grammar
rules) will be to write `Person $\rightarrow$ Man`. But you loose the
excellent spacing around operators provided by  LaTeX. So, the best
way will be to put the whole inside math mode, and use `\text` command
from amsmath package to specify the text.

From this solution, you get your text as text, as well as, you enjoy the
spacing around operators provided by TeX math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\text{Person}\rightarrow\text{Man}$

$\text{Person}\Rightarrow\text{Man}$


\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I am writing regular text like this: \begin{document} this is like this \Rightarrow therefore that is like that \end{document}

Comment: ok so is there another way of printing _something_ which looks like an arrow to the right without entering math mode? I just want an arrow, that's all... I am writing simple notes taken by hand from a class.

Comment: No, you need math mode to get an arrow.

Comment: @user43597 Glad that my answer was accepted by you. You can upvote that as well. :-)

Comment: would have to log in for that and am too lazy too recover my pw, sorry :/ take my purely human gratitude instead :)

Comment: +1 @user43597 If these are just notes (i.e. nothing you are going to share, *please*) you can use a somewhat dirty hack taken from plain: `\def\from#1\to#2\done{$\text{#1\unskip}\rightarrow\text{#2\unskip}$}` using it as `\from a \to b \done`.  I only suggest this because these are notes; I tend to write my notes not really thinking about TeX's macro expansion language.  Note that this type of thing has some consequences: if you plan to use `\from`, `\to`, or `\done` for other meanings within what you're writing, you'll have to wrap them in braces.

Comment: @SeanAllred - You should probably place your comment at the end of the OP's query rather than as a comment to an already-existing answer.

Comment: You also can define \myArrow as \ensuremath{\rightArrow} and simply write:  ‘Person \myArrow Man’ (respecting the spaces).

Comment: @Bernard This solution will loose the inter-operator spacing provided by LaTeX. See the part from OP, where he mentions grammar, that implicitly indicates usage of arrow in production rules of CFG.

Answer (score 1):

Use math mode for the arrow, this prevent's italic font:
A $\rightarrow$ B